# AJAX form submission based on ID not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

OK my AJAX form submission isn't working and I'm stumped. Below my code description.

**AJAX code**

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#addcomp_form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../inc/dataforms/addcompany.php',
        data: $('#addcomp_form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('company form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

**Html Form**

```
  <form id="addcomp_form">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Company Name">
          </input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Customer Type :</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
              <input name="type[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
                  Customer
              </input>
          </label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
              <input name="type[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
                  Supplier
              </input>
          </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="regno" placeholder="Registration No."></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="vatno" placeholder="VAT Registration No."></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" cols="5" name="regaddress" placeholder="Registered Office Address" rows="4"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Branch</button>
  </form>
```

**PHP code**

```
 include('../config.php');
 $types = implode(":",$_POST['type']);
 mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO `comp_companies` (company_id,company_name,company_type,registration_no,vat_number,registered_office_address) VALUES (,'$_POST[name]','$types','$_POST[regno]','$_POST[vatno]','$_POST[regaddress]')");
```

If anyone can provide any help it would be most appreciate

Comment: Please could you show at least the expected behaviour and the resulting behaviour ?

Comment: Show us the result you get and, most likely check that your url is pointing to the right direction

Comment: What exactly "_isnt working_"? Form not submitted? Data not stored in DB?

Comment: I guess data is not being saved in DB: `VALUES (,'$_POST[name]','$types'` you're missing something there

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Have you checked that the request was successful? Have you checked the server side logs for database errors? Also note that your PHP logic is wide open to SQL injection attacks. You should look in to prepared statements

Comment: Not getting any errors shown in console & the alert from the success is being triggered , just not inserting into the db
Regarding SQL injection its an internal system with no outside access and the people here barely know how to turn a PC on so not worried too much about that otherwise I'd be using PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Closely

`(,'$_POST[name]',...`

That might be where your problem lies, Be sure to take out the comma or file in the Missing post field which Possibly is the Company ID

You can also Extra Debug, by adding the error ajax function to your ajax code printing the error out in a console.log()

```
$(function () {
   $('#addcomp_form').on('submit', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: '../inc/dataforms/addcompany.php',
     data: $('#addcomp_form').serialize(),
     success: function () {
       alert('company form was submitted');
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
       var message;
       if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
         message = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
       } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
         message = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
       } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
         message = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
       } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
         message = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
       } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
         message = 'Time out error.';
       } else if (exception === 'abort') {
         message = 'Ajax request aborted.';
       } else {
         message = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
       }
       console.log(message);
     }
   });
  });

});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal on line 46 is what I get when the page loads and when form submitted now

line 46 is this line here 
 else {
        message = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
     -->> }
      console.log(message);

Comment: Just posted the data direct to the addcompany.php form and using print_r($_POST) i got all submitted data displayed
Array ( [name] => Test [type] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [regno] => 6666 [vatno] => 888888 [regaddress] => test,test,tes,le10 )

Comment: yep removed the comma and also the company_id column name from query as its an auto inc so doesnt need to be defined anyway

Comment: Replace with your query code and Try this `mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO comp_companies (company_id,company_name,company_type,registration_no,vat_number,registered_office_address) VALUES ('Company ltd','Customer','0182891','VAT_9282','Compton')");`

Comment: Check your connection status `$dbc`

Comment: however ('','Company ltd','Customer','0182891','VAT_9282','Compton') works and inserts

Comment: you have a Single Double quote `",'Comp...` which might output an error... what did you notice anyways?

Comment: really really strange ... just went back to the old query and added '', to the beginning of the insert value part  and its now working perfectly fine...

Comment: Lol' okay, be good to still review your codes, I'm sure you'll find out why, to avoid future code breakdown

Answer (score 0):

it's a `` not a '' (in the sql query )

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an event of submit for a specific ID, and you can't have multiple forms with the same ID.

Either you can go for:

```
$(SELECTOR).submit( function (e) {
//your logic
});
```

Or can try:

```
$(document).on("EVENT", "SELECTOR", function (e) {
//your logic
});
```

The query should be like this:

```
 mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO `comp_companies` (company_id,company_name,company_type,registration_no,vat_number,registered_office_address) VALUES (".$_POST[name].",".$types.",".$_POST[regno].",".$_POST[vatno].",".$_POST[regaddress].")");
```

If you have string type data then use single quote wrapping:

```
('".$_POST[name]."')
```

If integer data:

```
(".$_POST[name].")
```